# When I start my ternimal I get this error message, what does it mean?

Tags: linux, macos

-bash: /Users/IMAC/.udacity-terminal-config/git-completion.bash: No such file or directory
-bash: /Users/IMAC/.udacity-terminal-config/git-prompt.sh: No such file or directory

I have been learning git and version control for a couple of days, but error message kept popping up when I start my terminal. What does it mean and how can I fix it?

p.s. I have very little idea about how macos operates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try starting **Terminal** by doing a *"Spotlight search"* - that means press and hold the <kbd>⌘</kbd> and tap the <kbd>space</kbd> and start typing `Terminal` until it guesses you want **Terminal** and then press the `Enter` key.

In the **Terminal**, type the following and press `Enter`.

```
open -e ~/.profile
```

It should open your login script in **TextEdit** and you will see a line, probably near the bottom with `udacity` in it. This is the line that is going wrong. You can comment out the line by adding a `#` as the very first character on the line.

Then save the file but **do not exit** the editor yet, so you can revert changes if it's now wrong.

Now start another new Terminal and see if you get the error messages still. If you don't, you can exit the editor and you are all finished.

If you do still get the error messages when you start a new Terminal, or your new Terminal no longer starts, you better remove the `#` you added, re-save the file exactly how it was originally and get someone with more experience to help you.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question! When I did as you told me to, this came out: export PATH=~/.npm-global/bin:$PATHexport PATH=~/bin:/Users/IMAC/opt/anaconda3/bin:/Users/IMAC/opt/anaconda3/condabin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin

Comment: I don't see anything with udacity in it... I wish I had learned more about Linux System(or is it Unix? I don't really know)

Comment: Ok, you may be using a different startup script. Ignore the file you have open and try opening `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bash_login` to see if you can find some `udacity` stuff in any of those.